# Using WPF hardware accelerated drop shadow in ASP.NET server-side?

Tags: asp.net, wpf, dropshadow

I'd like to run drop shadow on Bitmap class in ASP.NET and I'd be really happy if GPU could do that. Any chance of this happening?

Update: I'd like to do that on server side. It doesn't really have to be ASP.NET app, it could be console app or windows service.

Comment: Do you mean render drop shadow on client side, or on server side into image then send image to client? 

Generally, it is not good idea at all. But you may run WPF application on server and render button to image. Unfortunately, I can't help you with such code.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is there is no hardware accelerated method to capture a visual to a bitmap.  RenderTargetBitmap uses the software render path.  You can however get RTB to work in an ASP.NET application, but it is not a supported scenario.

Answer (score 0):

How about running Silverlight embedded in ASP.NET?